# REQUEST_URI: echo$url : only get the number of url

Tags: php, get, echo

I have a website for recruitment services. 
When people respond to a vacancy, the url of the vacancy is echo'd in the response form (hidden field) so I see on what vacancy they respond.

I use this code for it on the response button, it redirects to the response form:

```
    vacature= $ url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];echo $url;
```

On the website the vacancies have links of the title, combined with the vacancy number: `website_url/vacancy_title-number`
For example: `www.test.com/director-sales-120`

In the response form I use this to get the info out of the url:

```
    echo htmlspecialchars ($_GET['vacature']);
```

For the new crm system we bought, we need only the number, not the rest of the url. How do I get only the number out of the url? Or how do I only get the number into the url ;)

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$str = "www.test.com/director-sales-120";
$arr=explode("-",$str);
echo $arr[2];
```

Comment: Thanks, how about when the url is variable? I have like 150 vacancies, the code has to work for all of them

Comment: Use `end($arr)` instead of `$arr[2]`

Comment: yes it will be working for all url as long as url format is "string-string-number"

Comment: So I have this working, the link is now showing the number only. (example: www.test.com/registrationform? 123) But how to I fetch this into the response form field?

Comment: $str = "www.test.com/registrationform? 123";
$arr=explode("?",$str);
echo $arr[1];

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did :    end($arr)     in stead of     [1]   
So another challenge. please help me on this. 
The mailform is send with help of a form.lib file, where I have to define the subject of the mail send with the form. 

I like the subject to be defined in a way that the vacancy number we just fetched into a form field, is also the mailform subject. Is this possible, and how ?

content of lib:  
      define( 'PHPFMG_SUBJECT' , "sollicitatie via site" );

function    sendFormMail( $form_mail, $sFileName = ""  ) 
{ 
   
 $subject   = PHPFMG_SUBJECT ;

Comment: mark this correct and ask new question its confusing

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $url, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

will print all numbers from the url

```
$int = filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

fetch number from string