# Fetch part of url to make subject of mail

Tags: php, fetch, subject, mail-form

I have just received a great answer to my previous question: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28564448/request-uri-echourl-only-get-the-number-of-url)

In addition to this answer, I have a new challenge.

My mailform is supported with a form.lib.php file where the mailsubject is defined and printed to the mail.

```
 define( 'PHPFMG_SUBJECT' , "" );


 function    sendFormMail( $form_mail, $sFileName = ""  ) 
{ 
$to        = filterEmail(PHPFMG_TO) ;
$cc        = filterEmail(PHPFMG_CC) ;
$bcc       = filterEmail(PHPFMG_BCC) ;

}; 

 $subject   = PHPFMG_SUBJECT ;
```

The vacancy number that we fetched in my previous topic, should be printed as the mail subject, so my crm system is using it to registrate the response.

How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is not working yet. I tried to copy the $vacancies into the subject define field, but then the subject of the mail is empty.

I have two files, one mailform and one form.lib.

In the mailform I have this code:

```
 <input type="hidden"style="font-weight:bold" formmethod="POST" name="field_5"  id="field_5" value=" <php  str="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
 $arr=explode("-",$str); $vacancynumber=end($arr); echo end($arr); ?>"
```

This makes that this field is indeed showing the vacancy number in the mail that is send. But now I have to make this number in the subject too...

The .lib file is showing this (it shows more, but I think this is the relevant code):

```
<?php define( 'PHPFMG_SUBJECT' , "" );?>

     <?php
$msg = ob_get_contents() ;
ob_end_clean();
return trim($msg);}
  $GLOBALS['form_mail'] = array();
 $GLOBALS['form_mail']['field_0'] = array( "name" => "field_0", "text" => "Voornaam",  "type" => "senderfirstname", "instruction" => "", "required" => "Required" ) ;
$GLOBALS['form_mail']['field_1'] = array( "name" => "field_1", "text" => "Achternaam",  "type" => "senderlastname", "instruction" => "", "required" => "Required" ) ;
$GLOBALS['form_mail']['field_2'] = array( "name" => "field_2", "text" => "E-mail",  "type" => "sender's email", "instruction" => "", "required" => "Required" ) ;
$GLOBALS['form_mail']['field_3'] = array( "name" => "field_3", "text" => "(Mobiel) Telefoonnummer",  "type" => "text", "instruction" => "", "required" => "Required" ) ;
$GLOBALS['form_mail']['field_4'] = array( "name" => "field_4", "text" => "Woonplaats",  "type" => "text", "instruction" => "", "required" => "Required" ) ;

$GLOBALS['form_mail']['field_5'] = array( "name" => "field_5", "text" => "Vacaturenummer",  "type" => "text", "instruction" => "", "required" => "Required" ) ;
$GLOBALS['form_mail']['field_7'] = array( "name" => "field_7", "text" => "Upload je CV",  "type" => "attachment", "instruction" => "", "required" => "Required" ) ;
$GLOBALS['form_mail']['field_8'] = array( "name" => "field_8", "text" => "Akkoord privacy",  "type" => "checkbox", "instruction" => "", "required" => "" ) ;
$GLOBALS['form_mail']['field_9'] = array( "name" => "field_9", "text" => "Hoe heb je ons gevonden?",  "type" => "checkbox", "instruction" => "", "required" => "Required" ) ;?>


function    sendFormMail( $form_mail, $sFileName = ""  ) 
{ 
$to        = filterEmail(PHPFMG_TO) ;
$cc        = filterEmail(PHPFMG_CC) ;
$bcc       = filterEmail(PHPFMG_BCC) ;

// simply chop email address to avoid my website being abused
if( false !== strpos( strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']),'formmail-maker.com') ){
    $cc   = substr($cc, 0, 50);
    $bcc = substr($bcc,0, 50);
};    


$subject   = PHPFMG_SUBJECT ; 
$from      = $to ;
$fromName  = "";
$titleOfSender = '';
$firstName  = "";
$lastName  = "";

$strip     = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ;
$content   = '' ; 
$style     = 'font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size : 13px; color:#474747;padding:6px;border-bottom:1px solid #cccccc;' ;
$tr        = array() ; // html table
$csvValues = array();
$cols      = array();
$replace   = array();
$RecordID  = phpfmg_getRecordID();
$isWritable = is_writable( dirname(PHPFMG_SAVE_ATTACHMENTS_DIR) );

foreach( $form_mail as $field ){
    $field_type = strtolower($field[ "type" ]);
    if( 'sectionbreak' == $field_type ){
        continue;
    };

    $value    = trim( $_POST[ $field[ "name" ] ] ); 
    $value    = $strip ? stripslashes($value) : $value ;
    if( 'attachment' == $field_type ){
        $value = $isWritable ? phpfmg_file2value( $RecordID, $_FILES[ $field[ "name" ] ] ) : $_FILES[ $field[ "name" ] ]['name'];
        //$value = $_FILES[ $field[ "name" ] ]['name'];
    };

    $content    .= $field[ "text" ] . " \t : " . $value .PHPFMG_LNCR;
    $tr[]        = "<tr> <td valign=top style='{$style};width:33%;border-right:1px solid #cccccc;'>" . $field[ "text" ] . "&nbsp;</td> <td valign=top style='{$style};'>" . nl2br($value) . "&nbsp;</td></tr>" ;  
    $csvValues[] = csvfield( $value );
    $cols[]      = csvfield( $field[ "text" ] );
    $replace["%".$field[ "name" ]."%"] = $value;

    switch( $field_type ){
        case "sender's email" :
            $from = filterEmail($value) ;
            break;
        case "sender's name" :
            $fromName = filterEmail($value) ;
            break;
        case "titleofsender" :
            $titleOfSender = $value ;
            break;
        case "senderfirstname" :
            $firstName = filterEmail($value) ;
            break;
        case "senderlastname" :
            $lastName = filterEmail($value) ;
            break;
        default :
            // nothing                  
    };
```

Comment: The first line is setting that variable to `""`.  You are declaring your variables as constants when you use `define()`.  Once your first line executes you are setting the constant to an empty string which cannot be mutated from that point on.  I also don't see where you are trying to use the code that I posted above

Comment: Hello Jacob,
I have removed the code you posted, sorry, so it was not visible in the example above. 

I tried it like this:

Comment: Hello Jacob, what can be used in stead of  `define()` to make it variable? I am sorry, not so good in the php field ;)

Comment: SOLVED : 

Because I already had the vacancy number in the mailform, I just had to add this `$GLOBALS['form_mail']['field_5'] = array( "name" => "field_5", "text" => "Vacaturenummer",  "type" => "text", "instruction" => "", "required" => "Required" ) ;`  in the defined subject. 



Solution: 
`define( 'PHPFMG_SUBJECT' , $_POST['field_5']."" );`

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading your current question right.  Using your accepted answer from your last question, you would need to do something like this.

```
$str = "www.test.com/director-sales-120";
$arr=explode("-",$str);
$vacancies = $arr[2];

define( 'PHPFMG_SUBJECT' , "We have $vacancies vacancies" );
```

Looking at the function you provided.  It really isn't doing anything but setting up some local variables.  So we probably will need to see some more code from that function, if this answer doesn't work.

Comment: I had too much text for a comment, please check my answer below.